# Dynamically Rebuilding a Terraform Complex Type

Tags: terraform

I could be going about this the wrong way, but I'm trying to copy a complex type and inject an object at specific point in a list of complex types. I have a working solution but it is not dynamic and I am forced to repeat myself for each point that I'm modifying.

The below works, but is not dynamic. I am required to repeat a block in the conditional merge statement for each property I need to manipulate.

```
locals {
    map_to_merge = {
        foo = "bar"
    }

    original_list = [
        {
            property_1 = "value"
            property_2 = {
                "nested" = {
                    string_property = "string"
                    map_property_1 = {
                        a = "b"
                        list = []
                    }
                    map_property_2 = {
                        x = "y"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]

     modified_list = [
         for item in local.original_list : merge(item, {property_2 = {
             for key, value in item.property_2 : key => merge(value,
                contains(keys(value), "map_property_1") ? {
                    map_property_1 = merge(value.map_property_1, local.map_to_merge)
                } : {},
                contains(keys(value), "map_property_2") ? {
                    map_property_2 = merge(value.map_property_2, local.map_to_merge)
                } : {}
             )
        }})
     ]
}

output "test_original" {
    value = local.original_list
}

output "test_modified" {
    value = local.modified_list
}
```

The output is,

```
  + test_modified = [
      + {
          + property_1 = "value"
          + property_2 = {
              + nested = {
                  + map_property_1  = {
                      + a    = "b"
                      + foo  = "bar"
                      + list = []
                    }
                  + map_property_2  = {
                      + foo = "bar"
                      + x   = "y"
                    }
                  + string_property = "string"
                }
            }
        },
    ]
  + test_original = [
      + {
          + property_1 = "value"
          + property_2 = {
              + nested = {
                  + map_property_1  = {
                      + a    = "b"
                      + list = []
                    }
                  + map_property_2  = {
                      + x = "y"
                    }
                  + string_property = "string"
                }
            }
        },
    ]
```

What I'd like to do is something like below as it allows me not to repeat the conditional merge statement for each property I want to merge with.

```
locals {
    map_to_merge = {
        foo = "bar"
    }

    original_list = [
        {
            property_1 = "value"
            property_2 = {
                "nested" = {
                    string_property = "string"
                    map_property_1 = {
                        a = "b"
                        list = []
                    }
                    map_property_2 = {
                        x = "y"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    modified_list = [
        for item in local.original_list : merge(item, {property_2 = {
            for nested, definition in item.property_2 : nested => merge(definition, {
                for key, value in definition : key => can(tomap(value))
                    ? merge(
                        value,
                        key == "map_property_1" || key == "map_property_2"
                            ? local.map_to_merge
                            : {}
                        )
                    : value
            })
        }})
    ]
}

output "test_original" {
    value = local.original_list
}

output "test_modified" {
    value = local.modified_list
}
```

But I am getting an error,

```
Error: Inconsistent conditional result types

  on test.tf line 41, in locals:
  40:                 for key, value in definition : key => can(tomap(value))
  41:                     ? merge(
  42:                         value,
  43:                         key == "map_property_1" || key == "map_property_2"
  44:                             ? { foo = "bar" }
  45:                             : {}
  46:                         )
  47:                     : value

The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
expressions are object and object, respectively.
```

Is there a dynamic/better way to do this or do I need to repeat the block for each property that needs to be manipulated?

Comment: This normally occurs when the declared type is `any`, so this is a bit odd. You may have encountered something to report to the issue tracker. Also note the literal question title of "modifying a map" would not be possible because declarative languages use immutable variable values. You are constructing a new `map` here.

Comment: Also super enjoy that `can(tomap(value))` to test the type; another example of the need for custom functions in Terraform. You can maybe also clean it a bit by replacing the `can` and ternary with a `try` function.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and suggestions @MattSchuchard. I'll play around with it more and might end up on the issue tracker.

Comment: Lol, turns out that switching to `try` gets around the issue -- no idea why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that switching from the use of `can` to `try` enables this to run as I'd expect.

```
locals {
    map_to_merge = {
        foo = "bar"
    }

    original_list = [
        {
            property_1 = "value"
            property_2 = {
                "nested" = {
                    string_property = "string"
                    map_property_1 = {
                        a = "b"
                        list = []
                    }
                    map_property_2 = {
                        x = "y"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]

    modified_list = [
        for item in local.original_list : merge(item, {property_2 = {
            for nested, definition in item.property_2 : nested => merge(definition, {
                for key, value in definition : key => try(
                    merge(
                        value,
                        key == "map_property_1" || key == "map_property_2"
                            ? local.map_to_merge
                            : {}
                        ),
                    value
                )
            })
        }})
    ]
}

output "test_original" {
    value = local.original_list
}

output "test_modified" {
    value = local.modified_list
}
```

Here is the output,

```
  + test_modified = [
      + {
          + property_1 = "value"
          + property_2 = {
              + nested = {
                  + map_property_1  = {
                      + a    = "b"
                      + foo  = "bar"
                      + list = []
                    }
                  + map_property_2  = {
                      + foo = "bar"
                      + x   = "y"
                    }
                  + string_property = "string"
                }
            }
        },
    ]
  + test_original = [
      + {
          + property_1 = "value"
          + property_2 = {
              + nested = {
                  + map_property_1  = {
                      + a    = "b"
                      + list = []
                    }
                  + map_property_2  = {
                      + x = "y"
                    }
                  + string_property = "string"
                }
            }
        },
    ]
```